Error whilst loading Celeba Dataset from torchvision
I have been try to download Celeba dataset with torchvision as follows
import torchvision 

image_path = './'
celeba_train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CelebA(image_path, split='train', target_type='attr', download=False)
celeba_valid_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CelebA(image_path, split='valid', target_type='attr', download=False)
celeba_test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CelebA(image_path, split='test', target_type='attr', download=False)

When i set download = True i get a MD5 checksum error and when i set it false and downloaded it manually it says it cant find it or it is corrupted.
I have downloaded the images and appropriate txt files from Kaggle and Gdrive and put it in the 'celeba' folder as follows
